# Gradle add folder with jars based on a System environment variable

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

Basically I've got project where I've to add some jars from a folder which is defined by a system environment variable.

I tried like:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: "$System.env.MYVARIABLE", include: '*.jar')
}
```

But it wont add any jar to my Gradle dependencies.

Also, in eclipse using GradleIDE I get null on $System.env.MYVARIABLE. On command line I get the actual path.

What is wrong here?

Thank you!!!